# Getting Invalid Field Name error on FeedItem

Tags: feeditem, upload, chatter-file

I have written the below trigger to block uploading of .exe files in chatter feed. Below is the trigger code -

```
trigger BlockHarmfulFileAsChatterFeed on FeedItem (before insert) {
    for(FeedItem f : Trigger.new){
        List<String> splitName = f.ContentFileName.split('\\.');
        String extension = splitName.get(splitName.size()-1);

        if(extension == 'exe'){
            f.addError('You are not allowed to attach files with this type due to security reason');
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the below error -
**Invalid field contentfilename for SObject FeedItem**

When I checked from Workbench this field ContentFileName is available and I can query also.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Regards,
Sudipta Deb

Comment: What is the api version of the trigger you are using?

Comment: API version is 36.0

Comment: Hi Shailesh, with your question, I thought of changing the API version from 36.0 to 35.0 and it worked. Strange right!! But thanks to you that you guided me to find the solution.

Comment: The field is supported in API versions 35 or earlier. Please see this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm

Comment: @ShaileshDeshpande I suggest please add this comment as ans to this question. It will be helpful for others.

Comment: @Ratan - Added as requested.

Answer (score 1):

The field is supported in API versions 35 or earlier. Please see this link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm